# How can I parse a typedef for a function pointer using clang API to get the function pointer name?

Tags: c++, parsing, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, libclang

I am currently building a parser for C++ code using the clang C API. The parser will process a  header file and generate a list of defined and missing symbols for it (it ignores include directives, so it will parse strictly the contents of the header). My problem is, if I have a `typedef` for a function pointer which takes an argument of an undefined type, such as:

```
typedef SOME_TYPE (* funcPtrName)(SOME_UNDEF_TYPE x);
```

the AST parses `SOME_TYPE` as the typedef instead of `funcPtrName`. If I replace `SOME_UNDEF_TYPE` with `int`, it parses `funcPtrName` correctly.

I thought I could use `clang_tokenize` to get all the tokens for the cursor and manually get the function pointer name, but calling `clang_getCursorExtent` on the cursor pointing to the typedef does not work correctly (the range returned is 0,0).

Do you know any way around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to work around the issue by building a list of all the tokens in the translation unit and passing that over to the visitor function. When I reached the `CXCursor_TypedefDecl` cursor, I searched for the `typedef` name in the tokens list and then checked if the next token is `(`. If so, look forward to the first token after `*`, which will be the name of the function pointer.

Here is some sample code:

```
   std::string symbol = clang_getCString(clang_getCursorSpelling(Cursor));

   ...

   case CXCursor_TypedefDecl:
   {
       auto finder = std::find(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), symbol);
       if (*(finder + 1) == "(")
       {
           auto next = std::find(finder, parserData->tokens.end(), "*") + 1;
           symbol = *next;
       }
       symbolData[symbol] = SymbolInfo{ cursorKind, fileName };
   }
```